# Is there a way to limit the number of decimal places returned using sequelize select query?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was just wondering if there was a way to limit the amount of decimal places that gets shown on the webpage when selecting from my view in my database. The datatype is double precision and the number of decimal places goes up to 17. I was wondering if there way a way to limit the number of decimal places to 2 or 3 when querying.

This is my controller

```
 const chw = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                    where: {
                        project_id,
                        commodity: 'CHW',
                        phase: 'predicted'
                    }
                });
```

This is my model. I'm interested in the savings_percent at the bottom.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Prjt_source_percent_each extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Prjt_source_percent_each.init({
    project_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    phase: DataTypes.STRING,
    commodity: DataTypes.STRING,
    comm_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    source_energy_baseline: DataTypes.REAL,
    source_energy_savings: DataTypes.REAL,
    savings_percent: DataTypes.DOUBLE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Prjt_source_percent_each',
    tableName: 'prjt_source_percent_each',
    timestamps: false
  });
  Prjt_source_percent_each.removeAttribute('id');
  return Prjt_source_percent_each;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A floating-point field contains an **exact** numeric quantity – that is to say, its float-binary representation.  They're turned into "something printable" so that you can see them – but something that prints as `2.32` might or might not be *exactly* that figure when you actually look at the ones and zeros.  For this reason, when dealing with floating-point numbers in a query (in any context ...) you usually need to use *small ranges.*  `X >= 2.32 AND X <= 2.32001`.

You can ask for the underlying binary value to be *formatted for output* using as many decimal places as you request.